# pytest, how to keep database change between test

Tags: django, pytest

I'm using the following inside `conftest.py`

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
```

it reads data from existing DB fine.
Now I want to run two tests and want the change I made in preceding tests to persist until test2 (until the whole tests in the file is finished)

```
def test_1():

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    user.username = 'hello'
    user.save()


def test_2():

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    print(user.username)        # expect 'hello' but it's not
```

- there's scope `session/module' and wonder what it means, session means the whole test run?

Following is what I have tried, but doesn't work..
(from bottom of https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/master/docs/database.rst)

In contest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }

@pytest.fixture
def db_no_rollback(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    # https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/master/docs/database.rst
    django_db_blocker.unblock()
    request.addfinalizer(django_db_blocker.restore)
```

in test.py

```
def test_1(db_no_rollback):

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    user.username = 'hello'
    user.save()


def test_2(db_no_rollback):

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    print(user.username)        # expect 'hello' but it's not
```

Answer (score 8):

You can reuse the DB with the `--reuse-db` option

Answer (score 4):

You can use pytest 'fixtures'

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_1():

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    user.username = 'hello'
    user.save()

@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_2(test_1):

    user = User.objects.get(email='a@example.com')
    assert user.username == 'hello'
```

in this case test_2 will have all db data from test_1(fixture)

Comment: However in this example, `test_1()` won't be executed as test but only `test_2()`. Is there a way to have `test_1()` also as test function but still keep the database changes from `test_1()` for `test_2()`?

Comment: yes, rename test_1 -> fixture_1, add one more method test_1 that use this fixture, it is all

Comment: Ah ok, so you basically outsource the database actions into a fixture, which you use in both test functions. Thx for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the test databases from being destroyed by using the `test --keepdb` option. This will preserve the test database between runs. If the database does not exist, it will first be created. Any migrations will also be applied in order to keep it up to date.
Look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) link.

Comment: This option is for django `test` command, not for pytest