# How to use pytest reuse-db correctly

Tags: pytest

I have broken my head trying to figure out how `--reuse-db`. I have a super-simple Django project with one model Student and the following test

```
import pytest

from main.models import Student


    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_1():
        Student.objects.create(name=1)
        assert Student.objects.all().count() == 1
```

When I run it for the first time with command `pytest --reuse-db`, the test passes - and I am not surprised.
But when I run the `pytest --reuse-db` for the second time, I expect that the db is not destroyed and the test fails, because I expect that Student.objects.all().count() == 2.
I am misunderstanding the `--reuse-db`  flag ?

Comment: Check out this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195531/pytest-how-to-keep-database-change-between-test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pytest, how to keep database change between test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195531/pytest-how-to-keep-database-change-between-test)